# adding space to list with consequtive separated words

Tags: html, css

I have a list with some items, where I would like to add some additional space between the words using strictly css!

This is how the html is looking right now, and the css is not there, so please just help me with that.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"> 
<p>List<->//more space item<->//more space number<->//more space one<->//more space</p>
<p>List<->//more space item<->//more space number<->//more space two<->//more space</p>
<p>List<->//more space item<->//more space number<->//more space three<->//more
space</p>
```

Comment: You should use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>` (unless it's just for your example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word-spacing property

```
p
{ 
word-spacing:30px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp

Comment: What if I want the space to be added inbetween not every word, but every second or third word?

Comment: @DinoExcel By this way you should need javascript solution with regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could add non-breaking spaces using:

```
&nbsp;
```

Though some browsers will collapse multiples of these into one space.

Comment: I would prefer css solution actually

Comment: @DinoExcel So you're saying that you want more space between each word? You could try the [CSS word-spacing property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp).

Comment: What if I need to be able to add space between not just the words, but combinations of words... You might have words that are separated but have meaning combined? Is there more workarounds for that?

Comment: @DinoExcel Probably not with CSS. You'd need to be more explicit about what you mean by "combinations of words", but from what you've told us I'm guessing the answer to your question is no.